# Async OkHttpClient Post

Tags: android

New to Android and Java. Need help with sending Post data from MainActivity. As i understand i have to use async, but it will not fire the doinbackgroud.
Also i do not know if the try catch is correct?
Console logging shows only "onPreExecute"

```
    public class PostHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String user, password;

    public PostHandler(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        Log.e("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("user", user)
                .add("password", password)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://my.domain/register_01.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute");
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("MyTag", "IOException " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Log.i("MyTag", "Button pressed");
    String user = "Bengt";
    String password = "qaz";
    new PostHandler(user, password);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the AsyncTask, yo need to call the execute(someString) method. In your case you could do `new PostHandler(user, password).execute(null)` not the best solution. If you're gonna use AsyncTasks (which is pretty deprecated BTW) I'd send the endpoint's url through the execute method as a parameter.

Otherwise move to Retrofit + RxJava or something more modern.

Comment: Ok, that was new to me. The fix worked an has to do for now, but i'll have look on Retro later on.
Thanks for the tip/help :-)